# XSLT template to match multiple nodes is repeating the html

Tags: html, xml, templates, xslt-1.0

I am facing issues while displaying the xml in html table using xsl. 
1. The html view is repeating with the below xsl and
2. unable to differentiate sub elements with the same name (Eg: name tag in the below xml).
The xml is having different kinds of information in different nodes as follows.

```
<employee>
    <address>
        <street>street1</street>
        <city>city1</city>
        <pincode>123456</pincode>
    </address>
    <personalinfo>
        <name>testname1</name>
        <phone>999999999</phone>
        <dob>23-09-34</dob>
    </personalinfo>
    <remarks>
        <education>
            <name>testname2</name>
            <college>college1</college>
            <gpa>7.5</gpa>
        </education>
    </remarks>
</employee>
```

and Here is my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="employee">
    <html>
    <body>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="address|personalinfo|remarks">
    <table width="630">
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>College</td>
        <td>City</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="//name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="//college"/></td>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="//city"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <span><br/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected result here? You have only one employee, so apparently you want a one-row table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your table structure, you want to move the table header up to the template matching the root node, and then get the corresponding detail of each employee using a **relative** (and explicit) path:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>    
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>College</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="employee">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="personalinfo/name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="remarks/education/college"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="address/city"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your response. Can I have more than one template with the same match and with different representation?

Comment: @Ramya I am not sure what you're asking - or why. It doesn't seem to have anything with the question here.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I am able to access all the nodes using relative path. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find an option to close this question. and I am trying to figure out to represent the same employee data in different formats like 2 employees information in one row in the same xsl. For that I am trying to use same match="employee" again which is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you post a new question, as this doesn't seem related to the current one. -- To close this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/245750

Answer (score 0):

The expression `//name` selects all the name elements anywhere in the document. That's not you want: you want the name element within the `personalInfo` or `remarks` that you are currently processing: that's `select="name"` for an immediate child, or `select=".//name"` for a descendant at any depth.

It seems odd to use the same template rule to process three elements (`address|personalinfo|remarks`) that have very different structure.